# For loop with if statement for ardiuno powered humidity control

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Really simple question but I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate a for loop in the if statement I have. Context: I have a humidifier I am trying to automate based on the humidity of the room. I'm using an ardiuno, dht11 humidity sensor and a servo. The humidifier knob has three settings (high low off) and so the servo has three positions. I have the code running so the servo turns appropriately according to the humidity level. The issue is that it fluctuates very easily. To correct that I'm looking to incorporate a for loop so that after let say 60 one second iterations of the humidity being greater than 55 the servo moves. I tried to add a for loop but it doesn't seem to be working.

But this is only my solution based on the little programming I know. If there is a better solution or even an equally viable alternative I'd love to know. I'm currently studying mechanical engineering but I'm finding that to really make something one needs a background in electronics and code. I'm trying to learn both independently through a series of projects and so I'm quite eager to learn. Hopefully this helps explain why I'm asking such a simple questions to begin with.

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;//create servo object to control a servo

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 7 // pin for humidity sensor ( also measure temp)

void setup() {
    myservo.attach(9);//attachs the servo on pin 9 to servo object
    myservo.write(0);//statting off position at 0 degrees
    delay(1000);//wait for a second
    Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
    int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN); // the follow is just so that I can     see the readings come out properly
    Serial.print("Temperature = ");
    Serial.println(DHT.temperature);
    Serial.print("Humidity = ");
    Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
    delay(500);

    if (DHT.humidity > 55) // here is where my code really begins
    {
        for (int i=0; i>60; i++); // my goal is to execute the follow code after the statement above has been true for 60 one second iterations 
    {
        myservo.write(0);//goes to off position
        delay(1000);//wait for a second
    }
} else if (DHT.humidity > 40 ) {
        for (int i=0; i>60; i++); // same thing here
        myservo.write(90);//goes to low position
        delay(1000);//wait for a second
}


else
{
     for (int i=0; i>60; i++);
     myservo.write(180);//goes to high position
     delay(1000);
}
} // end of void loop()
```

Comment: Please indent your code sanely.

Comment: Your `for` loops have two problems: The first is the condition, the second is the semicolon.

Comment: for (int i=0; i>60; i++); // this will never loop,  try i<60, and also loose the semicolon

Comment: I have done both of these and see no change. The servo still moves after one iteration of a condition being true.

Answer (score 2):

Just addressing your question, the following line is incorrect:

```
for (int i=0; i>60; i++);
```

Two things:
1) The second statement in the for loop describes the conditions on which it executes. The way it is written, it will only execute when i>60 (not what you want according to the comments).
2) The semicolon after the for statement makes the next block unassociated.

Correct that line to the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<60; i++)
```

See the following for more information:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm

It would probably be helpful to examine your compiler warnings, and/or set a higher warning level, to catch these type of things early (this is, of course, somewhat compiler dependent).

Comment: Thank you for that. I made the corrections but it still isn't working. I'm working in the regular ardiuno IDE so how would I go about setting a higher warning level?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you trying kind of de-bouncing at you need humid level stay in same range for some period.

First, I define conversion function to map humid level to state

```
#define HUMID_OFF 1
#define HUMID_LOW 2
#define HUMID_HIGH 3

byte state_conv (float humid_level){
     if (humid_level > 55) return HUMID_OFF ;
     else if (humid_level > 40 )  return HUMID_LOW ;
     else   return HUMID_HIGH ;
}
```

Second I will check changing of state and use millis() to count time while current state is steady. if counting time are longer than threshold then change the actual state.

```
 /*Global variable*/
byte actual_state;
byte flag_state;
void setup (){
// Do things that necessary
    float humid = dht.readHumidity();
    /*Initialize value*/
    actual_state = state_conv(humid);
    flag_state= state_conv(humid);
}

void loop(){
    static unsigned long timer = millis();
    float humid = dht.readHumidity();
    byte crr_state = state_conv(humid);
    if (crr_state != actual_state ){// if state is  changing
        if (flag_state != crr_state){
            /if crr_state change form last iteration then reset timer
            flag_state = crr_state;/
             timer = millis();
        }
        else if (millis() - timer > 10000){
            //if crr_state not change for 10000 ms (10 second)
            actual_state  = crr_state; // update actual state to crr_state
        }
    }
    // After this use actual_state to control servo
    if (actual_state == HUMID_OFF ){
        myservo.write(0);//goes to off position
    }
    else if (actual_state == HUMID_LOW ){
        myservo.write(90);//goes to low position
    }
    else if (actual_state == HUMID_HIGH ){
        myservo.write(180);//goes to high position
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

`DHT.humidity` returns a `float`, so if you want to compare, then first store this in an `int`, and then compare.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your answer is incorrect; you do not need to store a `float` into an `int` before comparing with another `int`.